# Parse LocalDataStore does not work when using Parse-Server - 'Method requires Pinning enabled.'

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore, parse-server

I have recently started using Parse-Server and have migrated my Parse App, now when I try to use Parse Local DataStore I receive the following error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Method requires Pinning enabled.'`

This is the code that produces the error:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MY_CLASS_NAME"];
[query fromPinWithName:@"PIN_NAME"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
```

If I initialise parse the old way by calling:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"APP_ID" clientKey:@"KEY"];
```

Then Local DataStore works fine, but if I initialise Parse the new way then I get the error:

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {

 configuration.applicationId = @"APP_ID";
 configuration.clientKey = @"KEY";
 configuration.server = @"SERVER";

 }]];
```

I am calling `[Parse enableLocalDatastore];` before Parse is being initialised, I've tried calling it after as well just to be sure.

Thanks for your time, hope you can help

Comment: I lost many hours looking for a solution. Maybe if put the msg erro 'Method requires Pinning enabled.' on title  You will help more people

Comment: @CCastro thanks. I edited the question like you said.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/815) and someone there solved the problem for me:

"if you are using configuration with initialization - you need to enable a local datastore slightly differently. Add the following line into the configuration block to enable it:"

```
configuration.localDatastoreEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Yeah this missing setting caused really weird issues that are not easily tied to it.